# Inconsistent rendering results with Mobile site in IE10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I'm in the process of developing a Mobile version of some websites using the MVC4 *.mobile.cshtml system.

Everything is working great *except* when I try and view the sites on my HTC 8x.  I get an outrageously large viewport, no javascript executing, offline touch regions and all-around incomplete pageload such that it doesn't function at all.  I'm trying to diagnose/debug and not having any luck.

Using IE10 locally with a User Agent string for Windows Phone 8 doesn't show the same behavior.  Further, using my exact UA string in any browser locally does not replicate the behavior.  I've tried the various viewport workarounds posted on the internet and those have had no impact either.

I'm not on a Windows 8 machine, so I can't install the SDK/Emulator, but I suppose I could upgrade if no other options present themselves.

Anyone have any additional ideas as to how to test/diagnose/replicate this?  I've been Googling for days and haven't been able to find any significant resource about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a combination issue with Output Caching and the MVC DisplayModes bug.